# Encrypted data is updating but other normal data is not updating in database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I have some fields which I want to insert into data in encrypted form. I can save that data in encrypted form but my other data is not updating/inserting like city,state, zip, and address.

I don't know what I am doing wrong:

My controller code:

```
             try {

        $profile = $this->doctorModel->find($doctorProfile['id']);
        $request->request->add(['updated_by' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $profile->city = Input::get('city');
        $profile->state = Input::get('state');
        $profile->zip = Input::get('zip');
        $profile->address = Input::get('address');


        $profile->registration_number = encrypt($request->registration_number);
        $profile->dea_number = encrypt($request->dea_number);
        $profile->npi_number = encrypt($request->npi_number);
        $profile->upin = encrypt($request->upin);
        $profile->save();

        return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Doctor Data Updated Successfully'], 200);

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $ex->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, city, state, and zip is not inserting/updating into database but encrypted values are inserting into database in encrypted form.

```
                 Request {#39
          #json: ParameterBag {#21
        #parameters: array:2 [
        "doctor_profile" => array:32 [
    "id" => 3
    "clinic_name" => "Mayo Hospital12301"
    "first_name" => "Dr. Brain17"
    "middle_name" => "Shahzad"
    "last_name" => "David"
    "cell_phone_no" => "111-111-1111"
    "phone_extension" => 123
    "doc_email" => "rajaunleashed@gmail.com"
    "fax" => "111-111-1111"
    "ssn" => "321"
    "address" => "Islamabad G9"
    "state" => "Federal"
    "city" => "Islamabad"
    "zip" => "24711"
    "npi" => 123123
    "speciality_id" => 2
    "medical_credentials" => 0
    "registration_number" => "0-98-98"
    "registration_expiration_date" => "2019-01-01"
    "dea_number" => "1-0-97-120"
    "dea_expiration_date" => "2019-01-01"
    "dea_issue_date" => "2019-01-01"
    "npi_number" => "0-987-124"
    "billing_title" => "SHAHZAD"
    "billing_employment_type" => "Contractor"
    "please_specify" => "Un-Employment"
    "nadean_number" => "90-87-1455"
    "upin" => "65-98-1011"
    "wcb_authorization" => "14-987-1"
    "wcb_rating_code" => "9"
    "wcb_date_of_issue" => "2019-01-01"
    "hospital_privileges" => "can_access_patient"
  ]
  "updated_by" => 5
]
    }
```

Comment: show us what `dd($request->all())` gives

Comment: Have you tried using `$request->input()` instead of the Input facade to get the form inputs for city, state, zip and address?

Comment: yes i have tried but it still the same thing

Comment: @Sohel0415  i have dd($request->all())  i have shown the result please see my edit question

Comment: try to do like `$request->city;` do you have same fields in database? and also check type of these fields is they really `var_char` or `text`

Comment: @syed1234 check the type of fields in database

Comment: Its confirmed its varchar